# apparent inconsistency read/write variable

Tags: tcl

I'm learning about Tcl just now. I've seen just a bit of it, I see for instance to create a variable (and initialize it) you can do

```tcl
    set varname value
```

I am familiarizing with the fact that basically everything is a string, such as "value" above, but "varname" gets kind of a special treatment I guess because of the "set" built-in function, so varname is not interpreted as a string but rather as a name.
I can later on access the value with $varname, and this is fine to me, it is used to specify varname is not to be considered as a string.
I'm now reading about lists and a couple commands make me a bit confused

```tcl
    set colors {"aqua" "maroon" "cyan"}
    puts "list length is [llength $colors]"
    lappend colors "purple"
```

So clearly "lappend" is another one of such functions like set that can interpret the first argument as a name and not a string, but then why didn't they make it llength the same (no need for $)?

I'm thinking that it's just a convention that, in general, when you "read" a variable you need the $ while you don't for "writing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Names are strings.* Or rather a string is a name because it is used as a name. And `$` in Tcl means “*read this variable right now”,* unlike in some other languages where it really means “here is a variable name”.

The `$blah` syntax for reading from a variable is convenient syntax that approximately stands in for doing `[set blah]` (with just one argument). For simple names, they become the same bytecode, but the `$…` form doesn't handle all the weird edge cases (usually with generated names) that the other one does. If a command (such as `set`, `lappend`, `unset` or `incr`) takes a variable name, it's because it is going to write to that variable and it will typically be documented to take a *varName* (variable name, of course) or something like that. Things that just read the value (e.g., `llength` or `lindex`) will take the value directly and not the name of a variable, and it is up to the caller to provide the value using whatever they want, perhaps `$blah` or `[call something]`.

In particular, if you have:

```
proc ListRangeBy {from to {by 1}} {
    set result {}
    for {set x $from} {$x <= $to} {incr x $by} {
        lappend result $x
    }
    return $result
}
```

then you can do:

```
llength [ListRangeBy 3 77 8]
```

and

```
set listVar [ListRangeBy 3 77 8]
llength $listVar
```

and get exactly the same value out of the `llength`. The `llength` doesn't need to know anything special about what is going on.

Comment: The output of `ListRangeBy 3 77 8` is `3 11 19 27 35 43 51 59 67 75`; it's length is `10`.

Comment: Thank you @Donal I'm starting to understand it better

Comment: @CDevel, this is an important lesson from this answer: "it will typically be documented to take a _varName_" -- Bookmark [http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm)

Comment: Is there a way to modify a list in-place from within a procedure (thus without having to return a new list and set it in the caller code scope) ?

Answer (score 2):

A different look at the question: what Tcl commands are appropriate for list *literals*?

It's valid to count the elements of a list literal:

```
llength {my dog has fleas}
```

But it doesn't make sense to append a new element to a literal

```
lappend {my dog has fleas} and ticks
```

(That is actually valid Tcl, but it sets the odd variable `${my dog has fleas}`)

this is more sensible:

```
set mydog {my dog has fleas}
lappend mydog and ticks
```